# проблема: не хешируется пароль при создании нового пользователя в админ-панели django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Создаю суперюзера в PyCharm. Захожу под ним в админ-панель, в ней же добавляю нового пользователя, но установленный новому пользователю пароль не хешируется. Далее выхожу из суперюзера и пытаюсь войти в админ-панель с логином и паролем нового пользователя и не получается войти:

> Пожалуйста, введите корректные username и пароль учётной записи. Оба поля могут быть чувствительны к регистру.

Что сделано?

Приложение accounts.

1. Создал модель `ForumUser(AbstractUser)`, отключил поля `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, соответственно вход по `username` + добавил поле `avatar = models.ImageField()`, также установил `objects = ForumUserManager()` и `USERNAME_FIELD = "username"`.
2. В настройках settings переопределил модель пользователя на `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.ForumUser'`.
3. Создал менеджера `ForumUserManager(UserManager)`, в котором прописал 2 метода: `create_user()` и `create_superuser()` в которых переопределил валидацию с `email` на `username` (`if not username:` и т.д.).
4. Создал в админке `class ForumUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): model = ForumUser`, с атрибутами: `list_display`, `list_filter`, `search_fields`, `readonly_fields` и `fieldsets`.

Почитав несколько форумов дополнительно создал формы для создания пользователя, изменения данных, изменения пароля и т.д. Указал эти формы в админке в качестве полей класса `ForumUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)`: `add_form = ForumUserCreationForm` и `form = ForumUserUpdateForm`.

Результат тот же самый. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Лучше бы прислали код места, где создается пользователь и по какому пути идет пароль. Скорее всего вы не используете `User.set_password` который как раз и хеширует

Comment: Для проверка - посмотрите что у вас в поле пароля в моделях. Если  в открытомвиде - то ответ выше